# Pass data from View to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm Trying to pass data from view to a controller.

```
window.location.href = "/DesignCoverSheet/Index?revNumbers=" + revNumber + "&site=" + siteID;
```

My problem is, revNumbers parameter consists of comma separated integers that I need to pass to the controller. Sometimes there could be thousands of integer values, so I don't think passing all these parameters in the URL itself is not a good solution. Do I have any other option to achieve this?

Comment: post alues using form post

Comment: if u really want to post revNumbers parameter through javascript then just use encryption and decrypt the revNumbers in controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert revNumber to array of integers and post to action and get in your action as below :

```
public ActionResult YourActionName(int[] revNumbers)
```